# MySql Stored Procedures Parameter Escaping

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

I came across something odd that I feel is to blatant to be a bug so I am guessing that I am doing something wrong: I have the following Table:

```
CREATE TABLE BlurbTest
(   
     ID      SERIAL NOT NULL
    ,Blurb   TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

With the following  stored proc:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertBlurbTest
(
     OUT ID INT
    ,IN  BlurbParm TEXT
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BlurbTest(
        Blurb
    ) VALUES (
        BlurbParm
    );
    SET ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and the following  C# code:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Settings.ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "spInsertBlurbTest";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MySqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
        cmd.Parameters["@BlurbParm"].Value = "let's do it";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Throws Exception
    }
}
```

Which is throwing an exception with the following message.
{"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's do it')' at line 1"}

Now, correct me if I am wrong, but is this not exactly the type of problem that stored procedures and parameters are intended to solve in order to aid against injection attacks?

Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, but the driver may not be correctly escaping these characters.  Is this yours?

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48247

Comment: This was eventually fixed in the trunk code. I'm expecting it to be in the 6.2.1 release.